# How to display data from database for a specific user from other table

Tags: php, laravel

I want to show data from a database that is about a specific user. I have a table when I fetch data from db. 
I can add user on my admin panel, but I want for each user to show specific data. I`m building a CRM. And users send data to MYSQL db.

Now I fetch this data and based on username I want  to create and user witch will be able to show just his data with his username. How can I do this in Laravel?

This is the migration.

```
public function up()
{
    //
    Schema::create('members', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->string('user')->nullable();
        
        $table->string('first_name')->nullable();

        $table->string('last_name')->nullable();

        $table->string('phone_number')->nullable();

        $table->timestamps();
        
    });

}
```

This is the controller how I show db table on blade.

```
function index(Request $request) {
   
    // fetch data from members table
    $members = Member::paginate(6);
    
    return view('list');
}
```

I use role to hide some data from user.

Comment: You should use user_id instead of username. It'll be easy to write eloquent relationships

Comment: i`m doing this         $table->string('user')->nullable();

Answer (score 0):

Make a Route

```
Route::get('members/{user}', ['MemberController::class', 'show']);
```

Then in your controller

```
function show(Request $request, $user) {
   
    // fetch data from members table
    $member = Member::whereUser($user)->first();
    
    return view('show', compact('$member'));
}
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

According the information that you are giving, i think that the gate must be something like this:

```
Gate::define('show-information', function (User $user, Post $post) {
    return $user->id === $post->user_id;
});
```

Where $user is an object comming from User model, and Post is an object comming from Post Model. in fact, you can replace Post model by the one that you want to restrict.

See more info in Laravel docs: [Laravel docs - Gates](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#gates)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tryed this but when i login as user  i can see all data. i just want to see only one user data. P.s      If a user have username: "test" i want to see just data what "test" is uploading on db not all users data

Answer (score 0):

**In your User.php model class add this relationship to get user's members**

```
  public function members(){
    return $this->hasMany(Member::class,'user','user_name');
  }
```

here we getting related data from the members table according to userName. you can read more on relationships in [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

**change your route to like this**

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->get('/members', ['MemberController::class', 'show']);
```

here we send the request through Auth middleware to get authenticated user

**In your controller try something like this**

```
  public function show()
{
    abort_if(Gate::denies('employe_access'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');

    $members=Auth::user()->members;

    return view('show', compact('members'));
}
```

let me know if something needs to change